# jQuery .each being applied to broadly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small script which makes an `li` element click-able and sets the location to that of a link inside of the `li`. This runs without error and my two `console.log()` calls are reporting back what I would expect, however, when you click on the `li` (whichever `li`) you are taken the `href` of the link in the last `li`. This doesn't make much sense to me as I thought I had properly handled the scope.

Please correct my understanding and let me know where I went wrong.

JavaScript:

```
$(".homeCTA li").each(function(){
    $href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    console.log($(this)); // displays the expected selector
    console.log($href); // displays the correct href
    $(this).click(function(){ window.location = $href }); // this is overriding all of the previous passes
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="homeCTA">
    <li class="left"> 
        <img src="first-source.jpg">
        <h2><a href="SearchResults.asp?Cat=1833">Yada Yada Yada</a></h2>
    </li>
    <li class="right">
        <img src="second-source.jpg">
        <h2><a href="SearchResults.asp?Cat=1832">Try the bisque</a></h2>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prefix `$href` with `var`, so that the variable [remains local](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals#Variable_scope).
Currently, you're overwriting a `$href` variable which keeps getting overwritten in the loop.

```
$(".homeCTA li").each(function(){
    var $href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    console.log($(this)); // displays the expected selector
    console.log($href); // displays the correct href
    $(this).click(function(){ window.location = $href; });
});
```

Instead of looping over the list items, you can also use the following code:

```
$(".homeCTA").on('click', 'li', function(){
    window.location = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
});
```

Comment: sonova... knew it had to be something that simple. Thanks. Will mark as accepted once the timeout elapses. Your suggestion is more succinct - I'll try that as well